# Left border for dynamic div

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to get `full length left border vertically` on a div.

Problem is that i can not fix the height of div as content is loaded dynamically and it can be short and long.

I tried below approach:

> Approach 1

**CSS**

```
div.right-col {
    position: relative;
}
div.right-col:before {
    content:""; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding-left:2.5rem;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 50%; 
    width: 1px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-col"></div>
<div class="right-col"></div>
```

> Approach 2

**CSS**

```
.right-col {
        position: relative;
 }
#borderLeft {
    border-left: 2px solid #f51c40;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-col"></div>
<div class="right-col"><div id="border-left"></div></div>
```

> Approach 3

**CSS**

```
.left-col {display:table-cell}
.right-col {
    display:table-cell;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
    float: none;
    height:auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-col"></div>
<div class="right-col"></div>
```

But none of above things are working. Border is only till where content is present.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z5eoz2gf/

Comment: @akash .. this worked for me.. cna u post as an answer so that i can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html

```
<div class="main">
<div class="left-col">sdfsdfsdf</div>
<div class="right-col">sdfsdfsdf
    <br>
        sdfsdfsdf
        </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.left-col {display:table-cell; width:100%;   background-color: red;}
.right-col {
    display:table-cell;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
    float: none;
    height:auto;
        background-color: green;
}
.main{
    display:table;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5eoz2gf/)

Answer (score 2):

Is someting like that what you are looking for ?

```
 <div>
      <div style="height:100%;display:inline-block;background-color:#FF0000;">LEFT</div>
      <div style="height:100%;display:inline-block;background-color:#0000FF;">RIGHT</div>
 </div>
```

Otherwise, it may be easier to use bootstrap and the row & col-xx class.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes referred to as the [Holy Grail Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Grail_(web_design)) and there are a number of hacks for it. However the first 'real' fix i believe is the [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here is how i would solve your problem: 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syzyb83p/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col left">Hi</br>Let's see how this works.</div>
    <div class="col right">Hi</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container, .col {
    display:flex;
}
.container {
    flex:1;
    flex-direction:row;
}
.col {
    flex-direction:column;
}
.col.right {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.col.left {
    order:-1;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use flex due to compatibility issues however sol looks clean